# date and time format according to requirement using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to format my time field:

```
<span> {{reportBuilderObj.creationTimestamp  }}</span>
```

The output is:

> 2020-10-15T06:10:07.861+00:00

I tried to do it using below code, but it's not working either:

```
 <span> {{reportBuilderObj.creationTimestamp | filer : 'dd/mm/yyyy '}}</span>
```

I need to do below format to be:

> 2020-10-15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the date pipe:

```
{{ timestamp | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
```

See this working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-bihvfu?file=home%2Fhome.html), using the values `1602845780824` as number and `2020-10-15T06:10:07.861+00:00` as string.

Comment: current my format is '2020-10-15T06:10:07.861+00:00' . but ur solution not working this output

Comment: my timestamp is in ms like so: 1602845780824

Comment: I have now tried with `'2020-10-15T06:10:07.861+00:00' ` and its working for me

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use moment. Using moment you can easily perform any date and time operation

I.E

```
moment('2020-10-15T06:10:07.861+00:00').format('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

see [moment](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @price if u can do this without moment, big help

Comment: @gihankumara you can use angular default date pipe for formatting. please have a look on following link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-achs53?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html